# Stickit: How to trigger a change event after every model -> view change

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-stickit

I have many events bound to elements in my view, though when I use stickit js to change values in my view by altering the model it doesn't trigger an onChange event.

Is there a way that I can trigger an onchange event for the current model:element after the setting the value in the model without having to write a handler for every binding? This would be for all form elements, input/select/textarea.

I want to avoid the following for each form element on the page:

```
bindings: {
    '#foo': {
         observe: 'foo',
         afterUpdate: 'forceChange'
    },
    '#bar': {
         observe: 'bar',
         afterUpdate: 'forceChange'
    },
    ...
},

forceChange: function(el) { jQuery(el).change() }
```

Comment: Trigger `onChange` of what? A DOM element? Why wouldn't your code just connect to the `change` event of the model?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific: when you say "it doesn't trigger an onChange event", what exactly are you doing?  Are you (or the Stickit code) calling `yourModel.set(something)`?  If so, is it calling it with the `silent` option, eg. `yourModel.set(something, {silent:true})`?  If not, the change event will get triggered, so either you have another event handler blocking it, or the `set` isn't happening in the first place.

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity. When I call model.set('foo', 'bar') the DOM element that binds to that model item changes in value but does not trigger the onchange method. I have tried with jQuery('element').val('new value') and it also doesn't trigger a change event. I am not trying to trigger a model change event but rather a DOM element change event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible hack (with version 0.6.3 only) would be to define a global handler which matches all elements:

```
Backbone.Stickit.addHandler({
  selector: '*',
  afterUpdate: function($el) {
    $el.trigger('change');
  }
});
```

Since handlers are mixed in with other matching handlers and bindings configurations in the order that they are defined, you couldn't use `afterUpdate` in any of your bindings without overwriting this global, all-matching handler since the bindings configurations are the last to be mixed in. You can read more about it [here](http://nytimes.github.com/backbone.stickit/#custom-handlers).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. If I had enough rep, I would vote your answer up! Didn't think of the asterisk!

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh, that comment clarifies matters.  So, in Javascript when you change an input's value "manually" (whether through jQuery or through `someElement.value =`) the browser won't, as you noticed, fire a change event.  Change events (and most other events for that matter) are only fired in response to *user* actions, not to Javascript.

Luckily, just as you can "manually" change a value, you can also "manually" trigger an event.  In jQuery the syntax for that is:

```
$(yourElement).trigger('change');
```

If you need to control things like `e.target` you can read up on the jQuery `trigger` documentation for the details, but that's the basic idea.

You can even chain the value-changing and event-triggering together if you want:

```
$(yourElement).val('newValue').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am hoping to globally invoke a change event on stickit update. As you can see in my example I am already using jQuery(el).change() which will invoke a change request just like jQuery(el).trigger('change'). Can stickit invoke a change request on my behalf rather than me having to put an 'afterUpdate' in each binding?